# How to add dependency to kotlin multiplatform projects with single build.gradle configuration

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have the following gradle module "calculator" whose `build.gradle` file looks as shown below. It works perfectly

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = "1.2.71"
        coroutines_version = "0.30.1"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version "1.2.71"
}

group 'mpp2-calc'
version '1.1'


kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'jvm') {
            compilations.all {
                tasks[compileKotlinTaskName].kotlinOptions {
                    jvmTarget = '1.8'
                }
            }
        }
        fromPreset(presets.js, 'js') {
            compilations.all {
                tasks[compileKotlinTaskName].kotlinOptions {
                    metaInfo = true
                    outputFile = "${projectDir}/build/classes/main/${project.name}.js"
                    sourceMap = true
                    moduleKind = 'umd'
                    main = 'call'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:$kotlin_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:$kotlin_version"
            }
        }
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }
        jvmTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
            }
        }
        jsMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-js:$coroutines_version"
            }
        }
        jsTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js:$kotlin_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url = 'https://dl.bintray.com/russhwolf/multiplatform-settings' }

    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

It is a multiplatform liblary, which has targeted the jvm and the js platform.

I have another module "someapp", that's build.gradle looks like this as well

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "application"

group 'mpp2'
version '1.1'

mainClassName = "com.asofttz.someapp.indexKt"

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    api project(":calculator") // doesn't seem to show any effect
}
```

My settings.gradle looks like this

```
rootProject.name = 'mpp2'
include ':calculator'
include ':someapp'
```

Now, I want to add the jvm platform target of the calculator module using gralde to someapp project without publishing to maven. Can someone help me how? I seem to stuck at this point, and I wanna move forward with this type of configuration

Extra question:
Suppose I add an android target in my calculator module, how do I add it as a dependency to an android project?

Comment: I'm also stuck with it in my project, however I found that gradle itself works with such a configuration at least for kotlin 1.3.0 (try to run 'gradlew :somapp:run'). It looks like IntelliJ has a bug at least with JVM modules. Android module could probably just work, because it is described in official tutorial. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got nothing wrong on your configuration, just bump you kotlin version to `1.3.0` and above. also use gradle version `4.6` and above.

To change your gradle version, just go into the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` change the the `distributionUrl` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`.

all set, sync and start debuging